# Powershell job with alternate credentials from Octopus Deploy

Tags: powershell, credentials, octopus-deploy

I've got an Octopus Tentacle running a deploy script. The tentacle is running as the LocalSystem account.

Inside the script, I'm able to do pretty much everything I need, aside from some archive bit. The archive needs to be done under different domain credentials because it's on a network share.

The frustrating this is that the code below works locally, but when run off the tentacles, it fails with the error

> ----------------------------------------------------[ Backup Nupkg ]---------------------------------------------------- Storing a backup
>   version of GeoSphere.1.2.1.1722.nupkg for the Development environment
>   Error    09:24:32 [localhost] There is an error launching the
>   background process. Error  Error    09:24:32 reported: Access is
>   denied. Error    09:24:32 At
>   C:\Octopus\Deployments\Development\GeoSphere\1.2.1.1722\deploy.ps1:121
>   Error    09:24:32 char:1 Error    09:24:32
>   + Receive-Job $job Error    09:24:32
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Error    09:24:32
>       + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (localhost:String) [], PSRemotingTran  Error      09:24:32    sportException Error    09:24:32
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : -2147467259,PSSessionStateBroken Info    09:24:32 HasMoreData   : False StatusMessage :  Location      :
>   localhost Command       : 
>                       Import-Module $args[3]
>                       Backup-Nupkg $args[0] $args[1] $args[2]
>                    JobStateInfo  : Failed Finished      : System.Threading.ManualResetEvent InstanceId    :
>   0c031592-4c2a-4f8b-b014-a5ba79be09f7 Id            : 1 Name          :
>   Job1 ChildJobs     : {Job2} PSBeginTime   : 13/11/2014 9:24:30 AM
>   PSEndTime     : 13/11/2014 9:24:31 AM PSJobTypeName : BackgroundJob
>   Output        : {} Error         : {} Progress      : {} Verbose
>   : {} Debug         : {} Warning       : {} State         : Failed
>   Fatal    09:24:32 PowerShell script returned a non-zero exit code: 1
>   Tentacle version 2.5.11.614

Here's the code

```
$pwd = convertto-securestring "[PASSWORD]" -asplaintext -force
$cred=new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "[DOMAIN\USER]",$pwd
$packageName = "GeoSphere.$Version.nupkg"
$backupPath = $($es.backupPath)
$artifactsPath = $($es.artifactsPath)
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    Import-Module $args[3]
    Backup-Nupkg $args[0] $args[1] $args[2]
} -ArgumentList @($packageName,$backupPath,$artifactsPath,"$currentDir\modules\ApplicationUtilities") -Credential $cred

Wait-Job $Job
Receive-Job $job
```

Here's the `ApplicationUtilities` Module

```
function Backup-Nupkg{
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,position=0)] [string] $packageName,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,position=1)] [string] $backupPath,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true,position=2)] [string] $artifactsPath
    )

    if(!(Test-Path $($backupPath))) {
        md $($backupPath)
    } else {
        Remove-Item "$($backupPath)\*" -recurse -Force
    }

    Copy-Item $artifactsPath\$packageName $backupPath
}

Export-ModuleMember Backup-Nupkg
```

What is the magic trick to getting this to run off of the Tentacle as it does locally?

Comment: Also, I tried having the Tentacle service run as the specified user, but then I get an IIS config issue that throws another wrench into the mix. These effing auth issues are painful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried the same thing without any luck, it seems like it's not possible to start jobs as a different user. In this similar question, Leblanc ended up using WinRM and `Invoke-Command` instead:

[run script block as a specific user with Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948655/run-script-block-as-a-specific-user-with-powershell)

(I don't think this is anything Octopus specific - the issue seems to be more of a problem with SYSTEM being able to start processes as a different user, or with `Start-Job` under SYSTEM, or perhaps both)

Comment: Thanks Paul. I changed the service account to one with admin credentials. From there I was able to do the copy without even needing to start a new job.